# Should "the" always be capitalised if it is part of a proper name?

Tags: capitalization, names

In brief, which of the following is correct? Alfred is fighting against a villain known as "The Penguin".

> Alfred punched the Penguin in the face.

or

> Alfred punched The Penguin in the face.

The second looks a little odd to me.

Comment: Isn't the character known as "Penguin" (like "Batman") rather than "The Penguin"?

Comment: Hmm, you're right! But I claim that the question is about an entirely unrelated character whose name is in fact "The Penguin".

Comment: I thought two of the other villains were the Joker and the Riddler, who could be called Joker and Riddler to their faces.  At the beginning of a sentence they would take a capital T, but a lower case t elsewhere.

Comment: In general, you have to look each one up in a list such as a gazetteer.

Comment: The question is whether "the" is part of the proper name. If it isn't, go with lowercase; if it is, capitalize. As for finding the answer to that question, I would find how the creator of the name wrote their name. For things like comic books where there are multiple creators and authoritative sources, I would go with the most common usage (consider using a [corpora](https://www.english-corpora.org/)).

Answer (score 1):

Taking a multi-word proper name that invariably includes a definite article, the Yorkshire Ripper, Google results for ["that the Yorkshire Ripper"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22that+the+Yorkshire+Ripper%22&sca_esv=1e69a4e84dfc1d5f&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=ogDBZfWADOO3hbIPkOymoAk&ved=0ahUKEwj12avfw5SEAxXjW0EAHRC2CZQQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=%22that+the+Yorkshire+Ripper%22&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiGyJ0aGF0IHRoZSBZb3Jrc2hpcmUgUmlwcGVyIkjscFCKC1j4a3ABeAGQAQCYAaYBoAG4CKoBBDEyLjK4AQPIAQD4AQHCAgoQABhHGNYEGLADwgINEAAYgAQYigUYQxiwA8ICDhAAGOQCGNYEGLAD2AEBwgITEC4YgAQYigUYQxjIAxiwA9gBAsICExAuGEMYgAQYigUYyAMYsAPYAQLCAg0QLhhDGLEDGIAEGIoFwgIFEC4YgATCAgYQABgHGB7CAgUQABiABMICHBAuGEMYsQMYgAQYigUYlwUY3AQY3gQY4ATYAQPCAhQQLhiABBiXBRjcBBjeBBjgBNgBA8ICChAuGA0YsQMYgATCAgcQLhiABBgNwgIHEAAYgAQYDcICGRAuGA0YsQMYgAQYlwUY3AQY3gQY4ATYAQPCAggQABgIGAcYHsICCxAAGIAEGIoFGIYDwgIGEAAYCBgewgIMECEYChigARjDBBgKwgIIEAAYgAQYogTiAwQYACBBiAYBkAYTugYGCAEQARgJugYGCAIQARgIugYGCAMQARgU&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#ip=1) and ["was the Yorkshire Ripper"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22was+the+Yorkshire+Ripper%22&sca_esv=1e69a4e84dfc1d5f&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=yADBZYXDAamhhbIP0NSzwAU&ved=0ahUKEwiFx7Dxw5SEAxWpUEEAHVDqDFgQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=%22was+the+Yorkshire+Ripper%22&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiGiJ3YXMgdGhlIFlvcmtzaGlyZSBSaXBwZXIiMgsQABiABBiKBRiRAjIFEAAYgAQyCxAAGIAEGIoFGJECMgsQABiABBiKBRiRAjIKEC4YQxiABBiKBTILEAAYgAQYigUYkQIyBRAAGIAEMgUQABiABDIFEAAYgAQyBRAAGIAESMMMUIkFWMAIcAF4AZABAJgBVqAB6QGqAQEzuAEDyAEA-AEBwgIKEAAYRxjWBBiwA8ICBhAAGAcYHsICCxAAGIAEGIoFGIYD4gMEGAAgQYgGAZAGCA&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#ip=1) show ratios of

- 47 : 3 (with 2 extraneous results)

and

- 48 : 2 (with again 2 extraneous results)

in favour of lower-case article variant in the first 50 pertinent results.

This is the usual situation, I believe.

Perhaps the situation is less clear with single-word nouns. There aren't many hits in a Google search for "played for the Arsenal" when one removes the attributive ("played for the Arsenal first team / youth team / side of 1983 / ...") usages, but the ratio is down to about 2 : 1 (but insufficient returns to draw accurate conclusions). But a search for ["Doctor Who" + "The Master"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Doctor+Who%22+%22The+Master%22&sca_esv=82ff3017660979eb&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=pDrBZezYA82GhbIP0OmhWA&ved=0ahUKEwjsuqeI-5SEAxVNQ0EAHdB0CAsQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=%22Doctor+Who%22+%22The+Master%22&gs_lp=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&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#ip=1) shows again a large preponderance of the lower-cased version where not sentence-initial.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! It looks like lower case "the" is the normal usage, but I'll wait and see whether there are any more answers. (aside: I'm sorry to see that this is one of those stacks where people downvote aggressively! I'll probably avoid it in future.)

Comment: There's some extremely good info / analysis on the site (though there's often disagreement about finer points too): at least use it as a resource. Possibly the downvote is because you've not included any research ('t/The Atom', 't/The Hulk', 't/The One-Above-All', 't/The Pink Panther', 'the Lord of the Rings' are proper names where the article is usually at least notionally included.  Using a search string such as "than the Atom" or "arrested the Pink Panther" cuts out sentence-initial capitalisation of the t.